# Regular Expression validator not working in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to .net and I'm stuck with a problem I want to validate my password field ,The password must be a alphanumericstring with special symbols and I wrote a code for that which is given below

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*]{8,15}$", ErrorMessage = "Password is not in proper format")]
public virtual string Password { get; set; }
```

But its not working if the password length is greater than 8 then its gives green signal for the string even  its only contain alphabets. How can I overcome this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z\d~!@#$%^&*]{8,15}$
 ---------------- -----------------
    |            |->match further only if there's any one of [~!@#$%^&*]
    |-> match further only if there's any one of [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: +1 Yep, that's more straight forward than I expected it to be.  Deleted my answer as I stand corrected :-)

Comment: This will allow any character in the password (as long as there is one letter/digit and on special character), because you use `.` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is - right now you're just checking for a string with length 8 to 15 that is made up out of these characters. If you want to make sure you have at least one special character, you need something like [!@#$%^&*]+.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure certain conditions on your string:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*]{8,15}", ErrorMessage = "Password is not in proper format")]
```

When you use the Regular Expression validator, you don't need anchors, the regex is automatically matched against the whole input string.

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])` is checking from the start of the string, that there is a letter or a digit somewhere in the string.

`(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*])` is checking from the start of the string, that there is a special character somewhere in the string.

`[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*]{8,15}` is then actually matching the string, allowing only the allowed characters.